# cant find server.xml on grails tomcat plugin

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have this code snippet on my app:

```
def listeners = grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.context.context.listeners
```

and the listeners list is empty (*but there is a running tomcat instance*).

So I guessed that the code is reading the **server.xml** file of tomcat but when I search it on the plugin directory I can not find it.

Comment: But still dont understand why listeners list is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no server.xml in tomcat plugin actually.** But there is a hook to it .

I found it here.

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/tomcat-plugin-where-is-server-xml-and-tomcat-users-xml-td1322273.html